# How to set the Size of an Android Galaxy Tab Emulator?

Tags: android, emulation, resolution, galaxy-tab

I have found a problem of access size on my Galaxy Tab emulator.

Some of its button are hidden from me so I am unable to run my application because I cannot see the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `scale display to real size` option when you start the emulator to scale the screen of the emulator.

I just found that the android plugin in Eclipse doesn't show this option if you just hit the `run` button, but you can still access it when you start the emulator from the `Android SDK and AVD Manager tool` which you can open from `Window -> Android SDK and AVD Manager tool`.

PS: I know this because my laptop screen resolution is 1024x768, most tablets and some phones don't even fit in this, this option is a life saver for me!

Answer (score 1):

Change your PC screen resolution. Increase resolution.

Comment: It is already on High resolution at 1366*768 which is high and recommanded by the sysytem or os.....

Answer (score 0):

IF you are calling the emulator from within eclipse, you will probably hit  a brick wall there.  i hope i am proved wrong, but, from what i have gathered, there is no access to how eclipse calls the emulator, so it leaves a big chunk offscreen, even at post 1080p resolution.

maybe it is my installation that is faulty, but when i try the answer number 0 above, i get an error.

failsafe solution: you must call the emulator using command line. then it is a piece of cake: use the SCALE option and you will be fine.

having said that, i bought a couple of android phones for development.  even on a machine overclocked for fullHD video rendering, it is still painfully slow to use the emulator.  read about ARM emulation for specifics.  bottom-line: emulator is an emergencial resource and not a tool for streamlining development.